# Glob matching in C# - StringType.StrLike is apparently deprecated, whats the replacement?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have recently upgraded from VS2005 to VS2010. In my .Net 2.0 code I referenced the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` and used the [StringType.StrLike](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.stringtype.strlike%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method to perform `glob` string comparison. I just noticed that according to MSDN, StringType is deprecated. Is there a replacement for the Like operator in VS2010/.Net 4.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the `LikeOperator` instead.

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices;

...

if (LikeOperator.LikeString(left, right, CompareMethod.Text)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Good call, I really wanted the `Like` operator, but C# doesn't have it. I was using the StrLike since that gave me the same behavior (and was suggested a couple years ago to me). Didn't see there was an exposure of the operator itself.

Comment: Wow, I never even knew this existed! I've always been doing this kind of thing with a Regex! +1000 if I could.

Comment: Yep, its why I was using the StrLike method for glob matching. I needed behavior that basically matched the glob matching when running a `dir` command in a dos console.

Comment: This does have the same usage warning as StrLike

Comment: @Mark which usage warning?  The OP was worried about the deprecated status of StrLike which is not attached to LikeString (AFAICT)

Comment: In the MSDN documentation for LikeOperator and its methods it states "do not use this, it's internal for compiler use only"

Comment: StrLike is broken - check out this test: 
        public void TestStrTypeVsLike()
        {
            string test = "Untitled - Notepad";
            string pattern = "* - Notepad";
            //StringType doesn't work - use LikeOperator
            Assert.That(StringType.StrLike(test, pattern, CompareMethod.Text) == false);
            Assert.That(LikeOperator.LikeString(test, pattern, CompareMethod.Text) == true);
        }

Answer (score 1):

Your link says StrLike is only for compiler infrastructure and you should just use the Like operator, which makes no mention of deprecation.  Are you using Like or are you actually using StrLike?

Comment: I totally missed the comment in the remarks section. +1 for making me reread documentation that could have saved us all time.

Comment: I was actually using StrLike because there is no `Like` operator in C#, but as JaredPar pointed out, I can use the `LikeOperator` class, which is what I am doing now.

Comment: I overlooked that you were using the VB stuff from C#.  You do realize `LikeOperator` has the same usage warning, right?  The "right" way would be to create a VB.NET assembly that calls `Like` and expose that to your C#.

Comment: I know there is a usage warning, what concerned me was that the StrLike method is on the StringType class that is now marked as deprecated. I know I am "misbehaving" ;)

Comment: You don't think this is apt to happen again in the future?  That is the point of the warning...

Comment: It may, and I will just change the code again, but for now it will work. I understand this is accessing the compiler service, but I can't imagine VB no longer having the Like operator, so I should still have a work around, and there really isn't another solution. Not sure why there is no Glob matching in c#. I can pinvoke into the windows API, and if I have to someday, I will.